# Can i change status of column(Approved || Not approved ) in database from android app...i am making a kind of approval Application

Tags: php, android, wamp

I am making a approval application and in this a user request for a approval and higher authority will approve it.I have done all the connectivity with wamp database but now how to change status of particular table from app?. Also i want to send notification to the user when his/her request approved or reject. Please help if anybody knows.

Thanks in advance

Comment: When the approval is requested, send a request to a php page and in tat page mark it as request for approval in db.

Comment: for notification u can request another http request to a page, if u want push requests, take a look at GCM

Comment: Please narrow down your question to specific areas in your codes that you need help with. As it stands, your question is too broad. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask